ADF/Databricks : The table is not delta format
Getting error, when trying to copy data from CSV (Azure Blob) to Databricks Delta table. Using ADF Copy activity, Blob Storage as Source, Databricks Delta Lake as Sink. Getting error that the table is not in Delta format, but it clearly is. Can't find a solution.
Source:

Sink:

Table in Databricks:

Error:


Can you preview data in the delta table in ADF?

I have tried the below approach:
I have created the Delta table In Azure databricks like below
%sql
create database if not exists d
create table if not exists d.t (ID int, name string)


desc  extended  d.t


In your databricks cluster edit your spark config and add the below cluster config

spark.databricks.delta.autoCompact.enabled true  
spark.databricks.delta.optimizeWrite.enabled true  
spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true  
spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<Storage Account name >.dfs.core.windows.net <Access key>

Next, I ran the pipeline
Results:
%sql
Select  *  from  d.t

ID  name
1   Dileep
2   Rakesh


